# Return dataset as json in c#

Tags: c#, sql, json

I'm really new to json, and I have browsed some of the prior questions regarding this topic. I think I am missing something basic, I have a table where "item" is the primary key, and I want to return json in the format of

```
{
    "item": [
        {
            "item": "12345",
            "description": "ece"
        },
        {
            "item": "34567",
            "description": "abcde"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried to serialize the datatable being returned from the database using

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt)
```

and I get the json format, just without the outermost "item":[  ]" block.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Edit: 
I am filling the datatable like so:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conStr);
String sql = "select distinct item,description from item where item like '" + id.ToString() + "%'";
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        }
```

Comment: Might be able to help if you posted code that shows how you retrieve data in this table because based on whether you query using a SQL statement versus just using the table name could make the difference in solving your problem.

Comment: Please see edit @cChacon

Comment: Ok.  Try @Xiaoy312's method - looks like a good solution.  Another method would be to simply define the table name for the Data Table object: `dt.TableName = "item"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an anonymous object to wrap it:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { item = dt });
```